# Unable to delete a file in /data/data with root permissions

Tags: applications, root-access, file-system, delete, app-data

I own a Moto G which is in 5.0.2 with KK bootloader. An app created a folder in `/data/data` which sustains in the memory even after uninstallation of the app. I couldn't remove the folder in any way.

1. I tried with Root browser, with terminal. Root browser says `Deleted successfully`. while trying to remove the folder, but it remains.
2. When I tried to remove it from terminal, it says `rm: 00160eb4bb6a2325_0: No such file or directory`, but it gets listed while using `ls`. This fails the nandroid backup with TWRP. :( Is there something I can do? Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: `ls` lists the file, but `ls -l` fails showing an error.

Comment: Seems to be a broken directory node. The only way to fix this is formatting the storage. I had this issue as well, but with an app folder that prevented me to install that app again.

Comment: Sadly, I even tried formatting the entire partition. The creep still remains. :(

Comment: Then you never formatted. What did you use to format your `/data` partition? Seems like CWM to me, which does not format using `make_ext4fs` like TWRP does.

Comment: Yeah, I formatted with CWM. Do you reckon formatting the partition with TWRP work?

Comment: IIRC CWM "formats" using something like `rm -rf /data/*`. It obviously does not format but rather delete everything. TWRP uses a proper binary that creates a completely new partition. As I have written: I was in a similar situation and only TWRP helped me. (Other recoveries might format properly as well, but I had a first-hand experience with TWRP)

Comment: Even TWRP failed to remove it. :( It said 'Unable to stat /path/to/folder/' and exited with error.

Comment: Finally, I had to repair the file system. Directory got deleted with rm -r after that. Thanks! :) I wish I could upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For delete folder `/data/data/` [only for rooted devices]

**Install adb tool**:  [if already adb install than skip this step ]

Notice that in this method you will only install the platform-tools like adb or fastboot.

1.1) Download:

```
Download the platform-tools for your OS from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html
Unpack it to <home-drive>\platform-tools
```

1.2) Mount:

The following steps are for Windows. If you need a different OS like Linux or OSX, have a look at this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42475/91312

1. Copy the folder path.Open the Windows Explorer by pressing + E`.
2. Right-click on This Computer → Properties.
3. Advanced System Settings → Advanced → Environment Variables.
4. Variable PATH → Add a ; (Semicolon) & your `<home-drive>\platform-tools`.
5. Save all & close.

**Commands for delete folder**

```
 $ adb root

 $ adb remount

 $ adb rm -rf /data/data/<folder-name>
```

**or**

```
  $ adb shell

  $ su

  $ mount -o remount,rw /

  $ rm -rf /data/data/<folder-name>
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already told that I tried deleting it from terminal. It isn't working any way.

Comment: your device is rooted ? than from adb shell it work

Comment: Yes, it is rooted. Adb shell works. But the deletion isn't.

Comment: it work for me, i delete one package com.example.example directory

Comment: Please read the comments on the OP's question too before you answer, so that you can add something new to the discussion. However, nice answer otherwise, so +1.

Comment: Is it possible to delete a folder using a single line, assuming you are in a batch file? If not, how do I do it in multiple lines?